# unable toncomplete build on adding android certificate

Tags: codenameone

I just finished building my app and I sent a build with no certificate and it worked...now on adding an android certificate, it reports a build error on my codename one dashboard. A help will be appreciated.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: Execution
>   failed for task '
>   :transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'. >
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>
> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
>   :transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
>   :transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease  (Thread[Daemon
>   worker,5,main]) completed. Took 4.163 secs.

Comment: Was the certificate created through Codename One Android certificate generator?

Comment: yes, it was generated using the android generator

Comment: Please post the build error details, if you have it and blur out or replace sensitive information.

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease FAILED
:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 4.163 secs.

Comment: Is this enough??

Comment: It's not clear enough to me, maybe someone else might be able to help

Comment: Ok. Or am I not displaying the right error

Answer (score 0):

I will need the full error as that point is already too low. I recall seeing some failures when punctuation was used in one of the certificate properties as Android chokes on that. It should appear in the error logs.

Comment: You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions. If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppressthe warnings with '-dontwarn' options. Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
         Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.You may need to recompile the code. Warning: there were 2 unresolved references to library class members.   You probably need to update the library versions. Exception while processing task :java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.FAILED(Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed

Comment: the above were the warnings I saw in the error log....it was long so I copied out these few. Helpful?

Comment: I'll need the full error logs. This doesn't contain the information I need. Notice that error logs expire after a couple of days so either provide a fresh link or place the full log somewhere

Comment: Good day Shai. Here is a link to the full error code.txt file
https://www.dropbox.com/s/hax19j12p6fsd0n/error.txt?dl=0

Comment: That's an error with your parse integration, I suggest adding the tag parse4cn1 to your question. What sort of cn1libs did you include? What are your build hints?

Comment: I used the cloudinary lib, boucy castle lib,cn1json lib,parse4cn1 lib

Comment: And there are no new build hints, except the default ones already there

Comment: Try creating a hello world project and add all of them to it and reproduce the build issue. Anything special about the parse integration? Did you install everything via the extensions menu? Did you remove something?